# Is $H^s(\Omega) \cap C_0(\bar\Omega) \subset H^s(\Omega)$ dense?

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

We work on a bounded smooth domain. Let $C_0(\bar\Omega)$ be the set of continuous functions with compact support and let $s \in (0,1)$.

Is $H^s(\Omega) \cap C_0(\bar\Omega) \subset H^s(\Omega)$ dense?

I cannot find any reference..

Comment: ok i probably misunderstood what is meant by $C_0(\bar\Omega)$ and deleted my answer

Comment: How is $H^s(\Omega)$ defined in this case?

Comment: @felipeh we do it through the double integral definition, see Sobolev–Slobodeckij spaces in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev_spaces_with_non-integer_k

Comment: I see.  Since you do not assume anything about the behavior on the boundary, what I can already say is that $C_0(\bar{\Omega})$ is not dense when $s>\frac{1}{2}$.  This is related to the fact that functions with jump discontinuities fail to be in $H^{1/2}$ and also to the continuity of the trace operator $H^s(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$ when $s>\frac{1}{2}$.  I am not sure what happens at $s=\frac{1}{2}$ and below for your question, though I will try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check *Partial Differential Equations* of Evans ? It is one of the best reference I've read on the subject.

Comment: I think this result cannot be find in Evans.